# Different routes on FatFreeFramework

Tags: php, routes, fat-free-framework

I have next route with a custom variable:

```
[routes]
GET /category/@item.html = \Controllers\Category\Item->show
```

It works as expected and I can visit next pages:

- /category/item1.html,
- /category/item2.html,
- etc...

I also have next pages (where XYZ is a known constant vlue):

- /category/item1XYZ.html,
- /category/item2XYZ.html,
- etc...

Is it possible to create separate route rule for such pages?
I.e. I want to use different controllers for item1.html and item1XYZ.html.

I was wondering that routes sections can be modified like this:

```
[routes]
GET /category/@item.html        = \Controllers\Category\Item->show
GET /category/{{@item}}XYZ.html = \Controllers\Category\ItemXYZ->show
```

But looks like no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Single curly braces are enough:

```ini
[routes]
GET /category/@item.html        = \Controllers\Category\Item->show
GET /category/{@item}XYZ.html   = \Controllers\Category\ItemXYZ->show
```